# Incompatible data type in parameterized query? (Java)

Tags: java, android, sql, admin

I'm currently working on an application that uses a SQL database to store the account information of users (username, password, etc.). In the app, there are both regular users and admin users. I'm also using a parameterized query, something that's still quite new to me, in order to check a user's admin status. The onCreate() method for the `users` table (which is what I'm using to store the user information) is shown below.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDB) {
    myDB.execSQL("create Table users(username Text primary key, password Text, email Text, 
    phone Text, admin Integer, userID Text)");
}
```

So, as you can see, the admin column stores an integer. In the context of my application, 0 denotes a non-admin user and 1 denotes an admin user. I'm using a parameterized query to check if a certain user exists in the `users` table and also has admin status (if the integer in their admin column is 1). The code for checking if the user is an admin is shown below.

```
// returns true if user is an admin, false if non-admin
public boolean checkAdmin(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("select * from users where username = ? and admin = ?", new String[] {username,1});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) // cursor > 0 if user exists in the database and has admin status
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Essentially the SQL query is just `select * from users where username = username and admin = 1`, but the problem I run into is in `new String[] {username,1}`. The "1" parameter is underlined red and Android Studio tells me that the required type is String. Again, I'm still new to parameterized queries and I'm confused as to why I get such an error when the `admin` data type is int.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring an array of String **new String[]** try adding the 1 as a string.

```
Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("select * from users where username = ? and admin = ?", new String[] {username,"1"});
```

Comment: I see. I've made the 1 a String before though, but wouldn't that pass on a String object into something that checks for int?

Comment: @Ralf SQLite will automatically convert to the correct type. As long as the string-representations equal what you would expect in an SQL query